# ASP.NET MVC - How to populate dropdownlist with another model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, models

one is called `PropertyModel` and the other is called `PropertyTypeModel`. The `PropertyModel` contains a `PropertyTypeModel` as you can see next:

```
public class PropertyModel  {
    public int PropertyID { get; set; }

    public PropertyTypeModel PropertyType { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [DisplayName("Property name")]
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

The `PropertyTypeModel` is this:

```
public class PropertyTypeModel {
    public int PropertyTypeID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]

    [DisplayName("Property type")]
    public string PropertyType { get; set; }

    public static List<SelectListItem> PropertyTypeSelectList()
    {
        using (Properties dataContext = new Properties())
        {
            return (from pt in dataContext.PropertyTypes
                    select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = pt.PropertyTypeID.ToString(),
                        Text = pt.PropertyTypeName
                    }).ToList();
        }          
    }
}
```

The `PropertyTypeModel` reads from the database, and creates a list with (for now) two values, "house" and "apartment". in the view, where i need to select the property type from a `dropdownlist`, the only way i've been able to do so is by hardcoding the list straight into the view, like so:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PropertyApplication.Models.PropertyModel>" %>
....
....
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PropertyType.PropertyType,  new[] {
new SelectListItem { Text = "House",
Value = "House" },
new SelectListItem { Text = "Apartment",
Value = "Apartment" }
}
, "Choose one") %>
```

I don't want this, since any changes made in the database, such as adding another type of property will mean re-coding the list in the view. besides, this code was given to me like this, and I NEED to use the `PropertyTypeModel`.

My question is: How do i populate the `dropdownlist` for with the `PropertyTypeModel` `PropertyTypeSelectList`? I haven't been able to find any info on how to achieve this. How to "read" the type model into the property model?

Please help, i've been at this for hours. If possible at all, the code to do so, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PropertyType.PropertyType,  Model.PropertyType.PropertyTypeSelectList(), "Choose one") %>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for few reasons: 1) This error comes up when doing m.PropertyTypeSelectList() - "The name 'm' does not exist in the current context". 2) The model m is not the one that contains the list. The PropertyModel is the one used in the view, while the PropertyTypeModel contains the list. the PropertyModel has a PropertyTypeModel as an attribute. That is the whole point of my question, how do i access the PropertyTypeModel from the PropertyModel used in the view

Comment: +1 this should do it. Alternatively (arguably a cleaner approach) you can have a `Model.PropertyType.PropertyTypeSelectList` property which you populate when populating the model.